# Is The One Ring playable with just two people?

Tags: one-on-one, the-one-ring

Is **The One Ring** RPG playable with just two people, one as the player and one as the loremaster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be; there is very little non-traditional about it. The most non-traditional element is the courage system.

The hope system, to some extent, is geared for 3-4 players. Since it has both individual and group dynamic elements, it may not be as good in a 1-on-1 game, but it should still work. The one element that is problematic is that one can always draw from the pool with group permission if one is the sole member of the group.

Also note: a larger group, in addition to having more hope in the Fellowship pool, has more diverse skills available, and thus is likely to need less hope spent in play.

The Travel System is brutal with less than 4 players, but that can be solved by NPC companions, or by playing a Dunedain.

Comment: That could explain why Aragorn-like characters could gather so much resolve - alone they had to worry about their own survival only, pushing on to fight and struggle for a higher purpose. :)

Comment: @OpaCitiZen Actually, no. The refresh of the pool is Number of Party Members + number of hobbits in the party. Aragorn on his own has only 1 courage to refresh for all rolls on the adventure. The party of 13 has 17 courage per session they can refresh amongst the whole... and so, if any one character is forced to use some, there is a deeper well to pull from to replenish it. Moreover, with a larger party, there is less likelihood of needing to spend some.